# How to test a probabilistic algorithm which is based on hash calculations

Tags: java, algorithm, unit-testing, hash

I'm trying to write tests for a load balancing algorithm which works as follows:

When a node fails, the algorithm computes thresholds based on loads of all other available nodes.

Then, it assigns endpoints according to the hash value of the endpoint ID and converts it to a number between 0 to 1, which is matched with the previously calculated thresholds to select the assigned node.

This should result in the endpoints being spread across all available nodes according to the proportions of their load.

The problem is, that this model is probabilistic.

The number of endpoints assigned to each node is dependent on the specific IDs of the endpoints, and this makes my result not be constant between different sets of endpoint IDs. Actually, I can't even tell what the actual result will be until after I run the algorithm. The result will change for different sets of endpoint IDs and with any change of the hash function

At first I thought of making the input random and test that the expected result is within some bound, but then there is always a chance to run into a failure if the input set happens to have IDs that do not distribute as I expect

So how do I test such an algorithm?

Comment: When I had the same conceptual problem, I went with a solution similar to your suggestion: define a bound such that it is met with very high probability. But that's in a personal-use setting; I'd be interested to see answers if they spoke about testing a library.

Comment: I don't think I completely follow the algorithm you're trying to test but when I've wanted to test similarly random things I've done (1) do the random trick but compute some bounds such that your test will fail with high probability if there's a bug and incorrectly fail with probability < 1 in 1 million or so if there's not a bug. Can't quite tell from your algorithm but often it's not too hard to come up with such bounds. (2) you can do what I described for (1) with a few different random seeds. When you get tests that pass just hard code those seeds so it can't false alarm.